# Low ambient noise in silent sections

Tags: recording, noise, ambience, piano

I used a pair Behringer C-4 connected directly to the Marantz field recorder in manual mode to record a grand piano in a live performance (not a studio). Now I have low amplitude ambient noice sounds like environment noise (room) in silent sections.

I tried to eliminate it with a standard NOISE GATE filter, but it kills the record itself.

Have you any idea or technology about the environment noise wiping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Izotope RX denoiser would probably be what you would want to use.  I don't think you want to remove the room noise entirely but just reduce it so that it still sounds natural and you still hear the "air".